# Firebase authentication returning false when reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a project with Firebase Integration and React.
I can register and login, but I do want some Guard in order to have access to the "connected" pages when I'm connected, or to be redirect to the default page for disconnected state if I'm not.

I coded the following for having the different Routes and set it in an App.tsx file :

```
const ConnectedRoute: React.FC<RouteProps>  = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  var route = <Route />
  var connected = isConnected()
  console.log(connected)

  if (connected){
    route = <Route {...rest} component={component}/>
  }
  else{
    route = <Route {...rest} render={() => <Redirect to ="/welcome" />} />
  }

  return route
}

const UnconnectedRoute: React.FC<RouteProps>  = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  var route = <Route />
  var connected = isConnected()
  console.log(connected)

  if (connected){
    route = <Route {...rest} render={() => <Redirect to ="/home" />} />
  }
  else{
    route = <Route {...rest} component={component}/>
  }

  return route
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/welcome" />} />
        <UnconnectedRoute path="/welcome" component={UnconnectedHome} exact />
        <ConnectedRoute path="/home" component={ConnectedHome} exact />
        <UnconnectedRoute path="/login" component={Login} exact />
        <UnconnectedRoute path="/register" component={Register} exact />
        <ConnectedRoute path="/events/create" component={CreateEvent} exact />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
  )
};
```

And for the firebase initialization I did the following :

```
export async function initializeApp(){
    console.log("Checking if app is initialized...")
    if (firebase.apps.length == 0){
        console.log("App initializing...")
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
    }
}
```

And the function to know if a user is connected (as a cookie) is this one :

```
export function isConnected(){
    const res = firebase.auth().currentUser
    console.log(res)
    return res !== null
}
```

Still, when I reload the tab, it's always returning me **FALSE** !

So, I was wondering how could I init the firebase server before the launch of the App ? Is this the current problem ? I currently do not have any clue about it and it frustrates me so much...

If you have already encountered such a problem, that would really help me !

Thank you !

Comment: Please replace the screenshots of your code with the actual code, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark that up.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's better like this indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication persists the user's authentication state in local storage. But when you load a new page (or reload the existing one), it has to check with the server whether the authentication state is still valid. And this check takes some time, during which there is no current user yet.

The typical way to get around such race conditions is to [use an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to detect the current user:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, redirect to "connected" pages
  } else {
    // No user is signed in, probably require them to sign in
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did this with the windows location but it's not really good when you're reloading the /welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer in comment with the code, it didn't work.

I did this for now (it's not that good but at least it works) :

```
const connectedPaths = 
    [
        "/home",
        "/events/create"           
    ]

const unconnectedPaths = 
    [
        "/welcome",
        "/login", 
        "register"
    ]

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        if (!connectedPaths.includes(window.location.pathname)) window.location.href = "/home"
    } 
    else {
        if (!unconnectedPaths.includes(window.location.pathname)) window.location.href = "/welcome"
    }
});
```